# Selenium c# how to handle multiple "Save As" dialog?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am testing opening multiples "Save as" dialog browser windows to make sure each dialog will download the correct file.
As a workaround I am sending user's keyboard keys to control a dialog. But it only works for one dialog with the focused window.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("uploadhere"));
element.SendKeys("C:\\Some_Folder\\MyFile.txt");
```

Is there a way to switch or select a specific "Save as" dialog?

Comment: Look up the [Alert Class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to disable the save as functionality:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Users\Usernname\Downloads\");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Now files will be directly downloaded, without the save as dialog.

Firefox has a similar setting: `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use Keyboard keys. 
You can use

> tab key

to navigate on the elements or the other dialog windows.
This will work 100%.